# Separate the results of VNCoreMLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, coreml, vision

I am trying to count the number of spokes of multiple objects on a button tap. But with the implementation that I have done, I am able to get the total number of spokes only and not able to segregate it. The code that I have done is as follows.

```
guard let pixelBuffer = currentBuffer else {
        print("Empty buffer")
        return
    }
    usleep(20_000)  // short 10 ms delay to allow camera to focus
    isShowingCapturedResults = true
    resetResults()
    
    let imageOrientation = exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()
    // Invoke a VNRequestHandler with that image
    
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: imageOrientation, options: [:])
    do {
        var coreResults: [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] = []
        let coreRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: detector, completionHandler: { request, error in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] else { return }
            coreResults.append(contentsOf: results)
        })
        coreRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFill
        
        var requests: [VNCoreMLRequest] = [coreRequest]
        var gearDetectorResults: [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] = []
        
        if activeModel == .toothCounting, let gearDetector = gearDetectorModel {
            let detector = try VNCoreMLModel(for: gearDetector)
            detector.featureProvider = ThresholdProvider()
            let gearDetectionRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: detector, completionHandler: { request, error in
                guard let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] else { return }
                debugPrint(" No of spokes \(results)")
                gearDetectorResults.append(contentsOf: results)
                debugPrint("gearDetectorResults \(gearDetectorResults)")
                debugPrint("Count  \(gearDetectorResults.count)")
            })
            gearDetectionRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFill
            requests.append(gearDetectionRequest)
        }
        try handler.perform(requests)
        debugPrint("Core Results  \(coreResults)")
        show(predictions: coreResults, boundingBox: false)
        show(predictions: gearDetectorResults, boundingBox: true)
        //////
        let counts = coreResults
            .filter { r in
                let rect: CGRect = {
                    let r = self.rect(for: r)
                    return CGRect(
                        x: r.midX - (crosshairSize / 2),
                        y: r.midY - (crosshairSize / 2),
                        width: crosshairSize,
                        height: crosshairSize
                    )
                }()
                return rect.intersection(view.bounds) != .zero
            }
            .compactMap(\.labels.first)
            .reduce(into: [String: Int]()) {
                $0[$1.identifier, default: 0] = $0[$1.identifier, default: 0] + 1
                //$0[$1.identifier, default: 0] += 1
            }.map { key, value in
                CountingResult(key: key, count: value, color: colors[key] ?? .white)
            }
        
        ////////
        debugPrint("Final Results  \(counts)")
        let vc = CounterResultsViewController(results: counts)
        vc.rootView.shareAction = { [unowned vc, weak self] in
            self?.presentShareSheetForResults(from: vc)
        }
        vc.onDismiss = { [weak self] in
            self?.isShowingCapturedResults = false
        }
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            present(vc, animated: true)
        } else {
            presentPanModal(vc, sourceView: captureButton, sourceRect: captureButton.frame)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        isShowingCapturedResults = false
    }
```

The results needs to be shown as below

```
Object 1 : 20 spokes | Color1
Object 2 : 28 spokes | Color2
```

But with the current implementation, the results are shown as follows

```
Object : 48 Spokes | Color
```

So can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @jobins-john Would you be able to provide a couple of examples of the images you're trying to count the spokes in? And how is the ML model trained so that it 'knows' what outputs to generate? It does seem to be a fun use of ML BTW, I'd love to know more...